# Running a PHP script using PHP OAuth extension on remote host.

Tags: php, oauth, pecl

I am using the following php script in order to access Fitbit API. The problem is when I run the script in local host it works fine but when I run it on remote server, it gives the following exception:

```
    OAuthException Object ( [message:protected] => making the request failed (dunno why)
    [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => -1 [file:protected] => 
    /net/www/example.com/htdocs/exampleFitbit.php [line:protected] => 41 
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => 
   /net/www/example.com/htdocs/exampleFitbit.php [line] => 41 [function] => getRequestToken
   [class] => OAuth [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => http://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token [1] 
   => http://www.example.com/exampleFitbit.php ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => 
   [lastResponse] => [debugInfo] => )
```

---

### **The script:**

```
 <?php

        $baseUrl = 'http://api.fitbit.com';
        $req_url = $baseUrl . '/oauth/request_token';
        $authurl = $baseUrl . '/oauth/authorize';
        $acc_url = $baseUrl . '/oauth/access_token';
        $conskey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $conssec = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $apiCall = "http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.xml";

        session_start();

        if ( !isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['state']==1 
             $_SESSION['state'] = 0;

        try 
        {

            $oauth = new               OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);


            $oauth->enableDebug();

            if ( $_SESSION['state'] == 0 ) 
            {

                $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_url,    'http://example.com/exampleFitbit.php');

                $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
                $_SESSION['state'] = 1;

                header('Location: '.$authurl.'?oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token']);
                exit;
            } 
            else if ( $_SESSION['state']==1 ) 
            {

                $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
                $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($acc_url);

                $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
                $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
                $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
            } 


            $oauth->setToken($_SESSION['token'],$_SESSION['secret']);


            $oauth->fetch($apiCall);

            $response = $oauth->getLastResponse();

            $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
            print_r($xml);
        } 
        catch( OAuthException $E ) 
        {
            print_r($E);
        }
    ?>
```

If there is any resource/tutorial/help/hint please share.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which line is throwing the exception - add some logging or die() calls in your try block to see how far it is getting before it jumps down to the catch block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it indeed is helpful. Actually this line throws the exception: $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_url, 'http://example.com/exampleFitbit.php');

Comment: Did you have to register with fitbit to get the required $conskey and/or $conssec? If so, I'm wondering if they somehow validate those per-domain, and the ones you are using are registered to your local / dev environment?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. I registered a new app on Fitbit and even with that the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use pcap/wireshark on the remote host to capture network traffic, but I suspect this will not work if you're not root.

So your only solution is to ask the fitbit support for help.

Other than this, you could try to simply fetch the profile.xml file via wget or curl and see if that works. If not, it could be a firewall problem.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am using a shared host, which leads to the problem of using PHP OAuth extensionon on it. And I am unable to find any alternative solution to it. Any suggestions?